# Series convergence: $\sin (n \frac{\pi}{2})$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> Determine whether the following series :
>   $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sin \left(\frac{n\pi}{2}\right) \frac{n^2+2}{n^3 +n}$$
>   converges absolutely, conditionally or diverges.

I know that for even natural numbers the expression will equal zero and that for odd values of $n$ the value of $\sin$ will go from $1$ to $-1$.

Could I theoretically reduce this series into a subseries:

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \sin \left(\frac{(2n+1)\pi}{2}\right) \frac{(2n+1)^2+2}{(2n+1)^3 +2n + 1}$$

And then treat it as if it were a standard alternating series?

Comment: You can reduce the series. Show using Cauchy Criterion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**

- Note that 
  $$
  \frac{n^2+2}{n^3+n}
   = \frac{1}{n} \times \frac{n^2+2}{n^2+1}
   = \frac{1}{n} \left[ 1 + \frac{1}{n^2+1} \right]
   = \Theta(1/n)
  $$
  Does this series converge?
- Adding $\sin(n\pi/2)$ in the front effectively kills all the even-$n$ terms and makes an alternating series out of the odd ones -- does the alternating series converge?

Comment: The alternating series should converge right?

Comment: @J.Lastin indeed

Comment: Okay and if i want to check for absolute convergence, can I do limit comparison with $\frac{1}{n}$, meaning that the series converges only conditionally?

Comment: @J.Lastin also correct

Answer (score 3):

Guide:

- We have $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sin (\frac{n\pi}{2}) \frac{n^2+2}{n^3 +n}= \sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{n+1} \frac{(2n-1)^2+2}{(2n-1)^3 +(2n-1)}$$
- Try alternating series test.